# How to delete the second colon and everything after it?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm currently trying to numb down a list to `[s1:s2]` and it is currently `[string1:string2: : digit]`. I have created an expression that only selects `[string1:string2]` but I'm having trouble copying the bookmarked lines. It will still copy the rest of the line that I don't need so basically I can't do that. What I'm trying to do now is create an expression which deletes the second occurrence of the colon and everything after it `[: : digit]`.

What is the correct expression?

Ex.

```
test:test1: : 123

test1:test: : 321
```

Comment: (1) Please mention (early) *in the text* of your question what tool you’re using.  (2) Try to state your objective more clearly. Are the brackets part of your text, or are you using them as quotes? (That’s not a standard convention.) Is the text after the third colon a digit or a (potentially multi-digit) number? What output do you want? The first and last characters of the first two strings? What are “bookmarked lines”? Are you talking about colons or semicolons?  (3) Show us what you have accomplished so far.

Answer (score 0):

- Find what: `^([^:]*.[^:]*):.*$`
- Replace with: `\1`
- Search mode: **Regular expression**  (Setting **. matches newline** is *unchecked*)